# I need to get date patterns in one column by using regex and DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hi i have date column in DataFrame, i need to get Date patterns from that columns.For example i have below column.I need to get patterns from this.

```
0       01/7/2022
1       01/8/2022
2      Jan/9/2022
3      01/10/2022
4      25/11/2022
5      01/12/2022
6       21/9/2022
7      01/14/2022
8      01/15/2022
9     May/16/2022
10       07172022
11     01/18/2022
12      10-3-2021
```

I tried this way

```
df_date=df_date.astype(str).replace([r'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|(0[1-9]|1[012]))(/)[\d]{1,2}(/)[\d]{2,4}'],['MM/DD/YYYY'], regex=True)
df_month=df_date.astype(str).replace([r'[\d]{1,2}(/)(0[1-9]|1[012])(/)[\d]{2,4}'],['DD/MM/YYYY'],regex=True)
df_mm=df_date.astype(str).replace([r'[\d]{,2}(-)(0[1-9]|1[012])(-)[\d]{2,4}'],['MM-DD-YYYY'],regex=True)
df_combi=df_date.astype(str).replace([r'[\d]{1,2}(0[1-9]|1[012])[\d]{2,4}'],['DDMMYYYY'],regex=True)
df_com=df_date.astype(str).replace([r'(0[1-9]|1[012])[\d]{1,2}[\d]{2,4}'],['MMDDYYYY'],regex=True)
```

The output should looks like this:

```
 Date   
0   MM/DD/YYYY  
1   MM/DD/YYYY  
2   MM/DD/YYYY  
3   MM/DD/YYYY  
4   25/11/2022  
5   MM/DD/YYYY 
6    21/9/2022  
7   MM/DD/YYYY  
8   MM/DD/YYYY 
9   MM/DD/YYYY  
10    MMDDYYYY  
11  MM/DD/YYYY 
12   10-3-2021
```

The showing numbers need to change.

Comment: please fix your question, read [the formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as you will likely never get an answer as is. You might also want to read the "How to ask a good question" guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you want to do when you have ambiguous dates? For example 01/09/2022 could be 1st September or 9th January?

Comment: Please can you add the lines for constructing the test dataframe? I'm OK with python and regex,I'm learning numpy but haven't started pandas.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a function that tries to convert a string to date using a list of formats.

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_date_format(text):
    fmt_map = {'%m/%d/%Y': 'MM/DD/YYYY',
               '%d/%m/%Y': 'DD/MM/YYYY',
               '%b/%d/%Y': 'Mon/DD/YYYY',
               '%d-%m-%Y': 'DD-MM-YYYY',
               '%m-%d-%Y': 'MM-DD-YYYY',
               '%m%d%Y': 'MMDDYYYY'}
    for fmt in ('%m/%d/%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', '%b/%d/%Y', '%d-%m-%Y', '%m-%d-%Y', '%m%d%Y'):
        try:
            datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
            return fmt_map[fmt]
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return text
```

If it succeeds it returns the first format that worked (or in this case, it uses a map to return a prettier format string). If none of them work, it returns the original string. (You could substitute a default value or an error message in place of the original value.)

You can add as many date formats as you need for your expected input, and put them in any order to deal with ambiguities like `MM/DD` vs. `DD/MM`.

You can then apply that function to the date column in your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ["01/7/2022", "01/8/2022", "Jan/9/2022", "01/10/2022", "25/11/2022", "01/12/2022", "21/9/2022",
         "01/14/2022", "01/15/2022", "May/16/2022", "07172022", "01/18/2022", "10-3-2021", "not a date"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date_string": dates})

df['FMT'] = df['date_string'].apply(get_date_format)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    date_string          FMT
0     01/7/2022   MM/DD/YYYY
1     01/8/2022   MM/DD/YYYY
2    Jan/9/2022  Mon/DD/YYYY
3    01/10/2022   MM/DD/YYYY
4    25/11/2022   DD/MM/YYYY
5    01/12/2022   MM/DD/YYYY
6     21/9/2022   DD/MM/YYYY
7    01/14/2022   MM/DD/YYYY
8    01/15/2022   MM/DD/YYYY
9   May/16/2022  Mon/DD/YYYY
10     07172022     MMDDYYYY
11   01/18/2022   MM/DD/YYYY
12    10-3-2021   DD-MM-YYYY
13   not a date   not a date
```